# Backward compatibility using excel interop in C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop, backwards-compatibility

I am using an excel interop to open an excel file, edit and save it with some other name in some other location. For that I have used:

```
workbook.saveAs(newFileName)
```

But it is prompting in the application for compatibility like how it is used to prompt while `saving .xls` file in office 2007. I have to click on continue in the front end application in order to continue. How can it be resolved?

Thanks in advance,
Sarath

Comment: Are you saving the file with an .xls extension? If so, the message is expected

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : Yes and I have to. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an `Application.DisplayAlerts` property which you can set to `False` during your `SaveAs` operation (and then set back to `True`).

Here are the details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.displayalerts(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Excel cannot open the file 'myfile.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file. I am geting the above exception while I try to open the excel in the app

Comment: You are trying to open an Excel 2007+ file in Excel 2003 or earlier. This is a newer XML-based format and you'll need to update your installed Excel version and/or the primary interop assemblies against which you are coding in order to manage those files.

Answer (score 0):

... I'm not sure I 100% understand what it is you're experiencing, but if it's a notification box that appears, try putting this line before the Save command:

```
ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
```

That should disable the alert from popping up....

Comment: Excel cannot open the file myfile.xlsx because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Comment: above exception is thrown while I am reopening it in the app

Comment: Given what you wrote in your initial question and this, they are two comepltely different issues - If you need help regarding this, you'll have to add more code into your question so I could see why it is that this error is being thrown...

Comment: I am opening an excel file which may either xls or xlsx. i have to edit it and save it in another file. so, I am using saveAs(newFileName). But it is popping up a dialog for compatibility check. When I used app.displayAlerts=False, the pop up is disabled but the file is getting corrupted and throwing the following exception while I try to open in app

Comment: Seems like all you should have to do is save the file with the correct extension, then - SO LONG AS you don't try and save Excel 2007+ features into a pre 2007 workbook, for example